# How to set seed for random sample selection?

Tags: r, random, splitstackshape

Based on a data frame with grouped samples I'd like to pick 5 samples randomly from each group. I can do so easily using the function `stratified` from package `splitstackshape`. But is it possible to set a seed as to make the selection reproducible?

```
data(iris)
library(splitstackshape)
stratified(iris, "Species", 5)
```

Comment: Yes, `set.seed(123);stratified(iris, "Species", 5)` gives the same output everytime. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: OK, yes, I tried that but didn't run set.seed() again before running stratified again! Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the code `set.seed(1)` before evaluating the `stratified()` command. This makes sure the random numbers are generated from the same starting point making them reproducible.